# How to create complex nested classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a series of Rails models that are nested and having trouble doing so. The basic run down is that `Institutions` live at the top of the chain and have many `IntellectualObjects`. `IntellectualObjects` each have many `GenericFiles`. So far, so easy. `IntellectualObjects` and `GenericFiles` both should also have many `PremisEvents`. This is where I'm having trouble. `IntellectualObjects` should have `PremisEvents` of their own, as well as linking to the `PremisEvents` owned by their `GenericFiles`.

If I set up the `IntellectualObject` model with just `has_many :premis_events`, I can create those events without issue, but when I try to retrieve a full list of events, the ones associated with `GenericFiles` are missing. If I add the line `has_many :premis_events, through: :generic_files`, beneath the above line, then I can access all of the events that the `IntellectualObject` should have, but I can't properly create `PremisEvents` for `IntellectualObjects` - the events get created but don't associate properly (or at all) with the intellectual object, so they don't end up in the list of events.

Is there a way to do this so that both types of events, those associated with `IntellectualObjects` and those associated with `GenericFiles` are retrievable from an `IntellectualObject`?

The relevant portion of the `IntellectualObject` Model:

```
belongs_to :institution
has_many :generic_files
has_many :premis_events, through: :intellectual_objects
has_many :premis_events, through: :generic_files
has_many :checksums, through: :generic_files
accepts_nested_attributes_for :generic_files
```

The relevant portion of the `GenericFile` Model:

```
belongs_to :intellectual_object
has_many :premis_events
has_many :checksums
accepts_nested_attributes_for :checksums
```

The relevant portion of the `PremisEvent` Model:

```
belongs_to :intellectual_object
belongs_to :generic_file
```

Comment: So a `PremisEvent` either belongs to a `GenericFile`, or an `IntellectualObject`? But never both?

Comment: Kind of. `GenericFiles` belong to `IntellectualObjects`, so the `PremisEvents` that belong to a `GenericFile` would also belong to the corresponding `IntellectualObject`. In addition, there are `PremisEvents` that belong solely to an `IntellectualObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more experimentation with my code, I realized that I just needed to explicitly define the associated `IntellectualObject` when creating `PremisEvents` for `GenericFiles`. Everything works the way it should now.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of defining the `IntellectualObject` for a `PremisEvent` that belongs to a `GenericFile` seems to me best for this use case. However if you are looking for a more scalable and general solution (e.g. easily add this same behavior to `Institution` as well), this is exactly what I created the [through_hierarchy](https://github.com/ozydingo/through_hierarchy) gem for. This would allow you to assign the `PremisEvent` only to a single resource and not worry about setting the relevant ids all the way up the chain. Using this gem, you could write

```
class PremisEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class IntellectualObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generic_files
  through_hierarchy [:generic_files] do
    has_many :premis_events, as: :resource
  end
end

class Institution < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :intellectual_objects
  has_many :generic_files, through: :intellectual_objects
  through_hierarchy [:intellectual_objects, :generic_files] do
    has_many :premis_events, as: :resource
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this still allow for `IntellectualObjects` to have their own `PremisEvents`, not owned by `GenericFiles`?

Comment: Not without defining either another association or scope, or just adding the scope manually. For example, you could use `intellectual_object.premis_events.where(resource_type: "IntellectualObject")`, and you could define that in its own scope or association. I think if this is a common use case then it's probably more intuitive to have the foreign ids (`generic_file_id`, `intellectual_object_id`), since that puts the intended use right there in the data structure.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm already doing. I think this is an interesting idea that I may try to implement at some point, but for now I think just explicitly defining the `IntellectualObject` for the events associated with `GenericFiles` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) with the help of `:class_name` option.